# Cleaning obsolete index data

Tags: couchbase

I have a view that only works with data of the current day. It does some aggregates for the current day and ignores older data. That means that at D1 I will no longer need index data from D-1.

I need to keep the index clean of older data because the volume I have to deal with this will polute the index and slow down view operations.

Is there a way to configure couchbase to clean the index ?

The other solution I see is to simply remove the index everyday at midnight so it only contains data from the current day, but that looks a bit brutal.

Thanks in advance for your feedback :)

Comment: Do you have to keep the old data? Would it be possible set that data with a ttl?

Comment: That's what I already do. I set a TTL to all my documents, but only using date from the current day will reduce my index by ~30% and then enhance performances

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to rebuild your index, so that it will not contain outdated data...

Couchbase has notion of view fragmentation (how outdated the view to compare to underlying data). You can configure fragmentation settings in couchbase console. Go to Settings and navigate to auto-compaction tab.

You can see there by default views have 30% fragmentation. You can reduce it (min 2%) so that your view will automatically rebuild once its reaches this threshold.

I recommend reading [Compaction Magic in Couchbase Server 2.0](https://dzone.com/articles/compaction-magic-couchbase)